# Install Laravel Framework on cPanel VPS

Tags: php, laravel-4

Laravel seems to be a great framework to take advantage of, but it's raising hell to install properly.

Apparently I followed all the directions properly and it's installed just fine, but when it comes to an autoloader, it won't do anything.

> Warning:
> require(/home/mywumbo/public_html/testing/Laravel-and-Angular-Goodness-master/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/mywumbo/public_html/testing/Laravel-and-Angular-Goodness-master/bootstrap/autoload.php
> on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> '/home/mywumbo/public_html/testing/Laravel-and-Angular-Goodness-master/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
> /home/mywumbo/public_html/testing/Laravel-and-Angular-Goodness-master/bootstrap/autoload.php
> on line 17

[image: This is what I see]

This is what I see when I list what's in my laravel directory.

So, is it a directory issue? I'm testing it under a /testing/ directory, is that my issue?

Comment: Have you run a [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) install?

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute:

```
composer install
```

Or

```
sudo composer install
```

Or, if you don't have access to your box via command line (SSH?), you will have to copy the whole `vendor` folder via FTP or any file copy utility you are able to use with your server.

To check if you have a vendor folder, execute:

```
ls -la /home/mywumbo/public_html/testing/Laravel-and-Angular-Goodness-master/
```

You should see something like

```
drwxrwsr-x  6 mywumbo mywumbo    16 Feb 26 09:37 ./
drwxrwsr-x 12 mywumbo mywumbo    14 Feb 26 09:37 app/
-rw-rw-r--  1 mywumbo mywumbo  2451 Feb 26 09:37 artisan
drwxrwsr-x  2 mywumbo mywumbo     5 Feb 26 09:37 bootstrap/
-rw-rw-r--  1 mywumbo mywumbo   697 Feb 26 09:37 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 mywumbo mywumbo 56230 Feb 26 09:37 composer.lock
-rw-rw-r--  1 mywumbo mywumbo   145 Feb 26 09:37 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 mywumbo mywumbo    11 Feb 26 09:37 .gitattributes
-rw-rw-r--  1 mywumbo mywumbo   103 Feb 26 09:37 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 mywumbo mywumbo   566 Feb 26 09:37 phpunit.xml
drwxrwsr-x  3 mywumbo mywumbo     8 Feb 26 09:37 public/
-rw-rw-r--  1 mywumbo mywumbo  1913 Feb 26 09:37 readme.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 mywumbo mywumbo   519 Feb 26 09:37 server.php
drwxrwsr-x 20 mywumbo mywumbo    21 Feb 26 09:37 vendor/
```

Last one, is your vendor folder, inside it there should have a `autoload.php` file, which is missing in the error:

Warning: require(**/home/mywumbo/public_html/testing/Laravel-and-Angular-Goodness-master/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php**): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mywumbo/public_html/testing/Laravel-and-Angular-Goodness-master/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Comment: I logged in as root in SSH and installed everything there. Install worked perfectly fine. Where is the vender folder?

Comment: if composer install worked fine, vendor should be there. Edited to clarify.

Comment: Edited my post to show you exactly what I see in SSH